# WP Query - if there are no posts with certain tag query other ones

Tags: wp-query

I'm banging my head on how to achieve this. I am querying posts that have 'popular' tag. But there are going to be times when I will have no posts with that tag.

This is my query.

```
$featured_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
    'tag' => 'popular',
    'tag__not_in' => array($tag->term_id),
));
```

How do I say that if there are no articles with 'popular' tag to show all other articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP_Query doesn't have a fallback system in it. It just executes the query with the given parameters.

One option is just to check, if the first query has any posts and if not, then run another query with different parameters.

Another way is to conditionally build up the parameters. So first get the tag term and if it has any posts attached include it in the parameters.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
);

$category = get_query_var('cat');
if ( $category && is_int($category) ) {
  $args['cat'] => $category;
}

$popular_tag = get_term_by( 'slug', 'popular', 'post_tag' );
// Does the tag exist and does it have any post attached to it
if ( $popular_tag && $popular_tag->count ) {
  $args['tag_id'] => $popular_tag->term_id;
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

From WP_Term class reference, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/

> Cached object count for this term.